# Catalog Search reindex not completing

Tags: magento-2.1.7, indexer

I have imported ~17k products, and when reindexing the catalogsearch_fulltext index does not complete. I have tried resetting and reindexing with

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalogsearch_fulltext
php -d memnory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

The process starts, but appears to fail without any warning/error. If I run reindex again, it returns

```
Catalog Search index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
```

I cannot see any locks in the database.

Is there another way to force this to reindex?

Answer (score 0):

You need run command `bin/magento indexer:reset catalogsearch_fulltext` and then start reindex again.

Comment: I have done that, as stated in my question. When it kicks off, it just seems to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 2.1.8 allowed me to re-index successfully